# RestEasy custom action on every request

Tags: java, resteasy

I would like to invoke some custom method when a REST call has finished, looking up annotations on the originating method and the generated response.

I know you can use the `PostProcessInterceptor` or `MessageBodyWriterInterceptor` for this task but they **do not** get invoked in case of an exception.

My current solution is such that every method throws a special exception which is then handled by a custom `ExceptionMapper`, but there I have no information about the original request and where it came from.

Is there a global wide handler you can bind to in order to get the information about the original request in case of an exception?

And yes I know about this question: [RestEasy Post Process Interceptor chain not traversed when response created by ExceptionMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937998/resteasy-post-process-interceptor-chain-not-traversed-when-response-created-by-e?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question.

One can inject the original request into the `ExceptionMapper` and react or perform a custom action accordingly.

```
@Provider
public class MyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {


    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Throwable exception)
    {

         // trigger event
         triggerOnExceptionEvent(request, exception);
    }
...
}
```